# How to make better falling blocks?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Me and a friend are trying to learn Unity and c# so we can try and make a game. My friend is having trouble with logical operators, so I am trying to make a simple program that cause blocks to fall when you press certain key combos.(he gets very hung up on things without a visual aid) I was able to put something together but its very ruff and I feel there are a lot better ways to go about it. Here's what I have managed to write with a lot of trial and error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Falling : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fallspeed = 8.0f;
    bool a;
    bool b;
    private GameObject box_0;
    private GameObject box_2;
    private GameObject box_3;
    private GameObject box_4;
    private GameObject box_5;
    private GameObject box_6;
    private GameObject clone;
    private GameObject clone1;
    private GameObject clone2;
    private GameObject clone3;
    private GameObject clone4;
    private GameObject clone5;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        a = false;
        b = false;
        box_0 = GameObject.Find("box_0");
        box_2 = GameObject.Find("box_2");
        box_3 = GameObject.Find("box_3");
        box_4 = GameObject.Find("box_4");
        box_5 = GameObject.Find("box_5");
        box_6 = GameObject.Find("box_6");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // makes box_0 fall if a key is pressed
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone = Instantiate (box_0, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.B) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone1 = Instantiate (box_2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Q) && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.E)) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone2 = Instantiate (box_3, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.R) || (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.S)) ) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone3 = Instantiate (box_4, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.U)) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone4 = Instantiate (box_5, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.I)) {
            a = true;
            if (a) {
                clone5 = Instantiate (box_6, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                a = false;
            }
        }
        //makes clones fall if they exist
        if (clone != null) {
            clone.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else if (clone1 != null) {
            clone1.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else if (clone2 != null) {
            clone2.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else if (clone3 != null) {
            clone3.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else if (clone4 != null) {
            clone4.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } else {
            if (clone5 != null) {
                clone5.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the code is functional but has problems. for one if I spawn more then one of the same clone they get stuck and I dont think I handled the null gameobject very well at all. could anyone give me some advice on how to do this better?

(also in case its relevant there are six colored blocks lined up at the top of the screen, when certain keys are pressed a clone of the block that is being referenced is created and made to fall. the block has a collider and when it hits the bottom of the screen it hits another collider and gets destroyed.)

Comment: I feel there are significantly easier ways of explaining logical operations than a program like this, especially since I see very few logical operators here in the first place.

Comment: you are probably right, this is just the ideal i came up with in my head and to be honest its not even finished all the way. if you have any suggestions on better ways to approach this I'm more than open. I'm also very new to coding so any advice on things i did wrong or could have done better would also be welcome.

Comment: I suggest creating a box class and instantiating that. Either attach a rigidbody and use gravity to move them down or put the falling code in that class's update function. That'd clear up about half your code here. Just skip playing with bools and simply spawn a box on keypress being you set it to false directly afterwards anyway. Also, if you're instantiating more than 1 box named "clone1" or "clone2", etc, you're losing your reference to it and therefor it stops falling. Put the new boxes in a list and simply iterate through them if nothing else.

Comment: @DavidAdams Just show him a truth table and force him to draw one up for every logical operator. You can't go into programming, especially a complicated area like game programming, without a thorough understanding of basic logical operations. I think you guys need to take a step back and work on simpler stuff first. It'll prove to be an exercise is frustration otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you can definitely improve...

---

1. When you have a collection of instances, use a data structure that is appropriate for collections.

---

Instead of this:

```
private GameObject box_0;
private GameObject box_2; //<<<That typo tho!
private GameObject box_3;
private GameObject box_4;
private GameObject box_5;
private GameObject box_6;
//...
```

You can and should do this:

```
private GameObject[] boxes = new GameObject[6];
private List<GameObject> clones = new List<GameObject>();
```

These are, respectively, an `array` and a `list`; two of many of C#'s collection data types.

- Arrays are excellent for *fixed* amounts of elements of a certain type of object.
- Lists are excellent for *dynamic* amounts of elements.

Other types include: `Set<>`, `Dictionary<>`, `Queue<>`, `Stack<>` and more; each has it's own optimal use-case.

---

2. Remember that you're programming. Whenever possible, try to make the *machine* be the one doing the hard work.

---

Instead of this:

```
box_0 = GameObject.Find("box_0");
box_2 = GameObject.Find("box_2"); //<<<That typo tho!
box_3 = GameObject.Find("box_3");
box_4 = GameObject.Find("box_4");
box_5 = GameObject.Find("box_5");
box_6 = GameObject.Find("box_6");
```

You can have this:

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    boxes[i] = GameObject.Find("box_"+i);
```

This is called a *loop*. It's the way to do this when you need a repetitive task done multiple times. More specifically, this is a `for` loop.

There are also:

- `while` (`while(/*condition evaluated before loop*/){/*some code*/}`)
- `do-while` (`do{/*some code*/}while(/*condition evaluated after loop*/)`)
- `for-each` (`foreach(var element in someCollection){/*some code*/}`)
- And others.

---

3. Be aware of *redundancies*!

---

The `a` variable in:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
    a = true;
    if (a) {
        clone = Instantiate (box_0, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        a = false;
    }
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.B) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {
    a = true;
    if (a) {
        clone1 = Instantiate (box_2, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        a = false;
    }
}
//...
```

Does ***nothing***! And `b` isn't even used!

---

4. If you *clones* are dynamic (can sometimes be null,and sometimes not), you can handle them dynamically!

---

If you keep the `clones` *list* as a list of *existing* clones, rather than a list of *possible* clones, it will be much easier to automatize stuff later!

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A))
    clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[0], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.B) || Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C))
    clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[1], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
//...
```

Later, instead of this:

```
if (clone != null) {
    clone.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
} else if (clone1 != null) {
    clone1.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
} else if (clone2 != null) {
    clone2.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
} else if (clone3 != null) {
    clone3.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
} else if (clone4 != null) {
    clone4.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
} else {
    if (clone5 != null) {
        clone5.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

You can do this:

```
foreach(var clone in clones)
    clone.transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

---

5. You should be consistent.

---

```
private GameObject box_0;
private GameObject box_2; //<<<NOPE! should be box_1!
//And others should follow the sequence from 1!
private GameObject box_3;
private GameObject box_4;
private GameObject box_5;
private GameObject box_6;

private GameObject clone; //<<<NOPE! Should be 'clone_0', 'clone_1' etc...
private GameObject clone1;
private GameObject clone2;
private GameObject clone3;
private GameObject clone4;
private GameObject clone5;
```

Comment: Pretty much summed everything I wanted to comment on the OP's mistakes. The only thing I would like to mention is that in your 4th point, the foreach loop and OP's if elses arent identical. Actually, the thing that hey arent identical is better, since OP complained that if one falls the others freeze, your solution will solve that problem (since in his case only one of the translates are being called and in your every one is being called in a loop).

Comment: IMHO there might be a problem in all list-based approaches since question mentioned that "the block has a collider and when it hits the bottom of the screen it hits another collider and gets destroyed". Without knowing how destroying is being handled we might end up with a list containing destroyed game objects. I think it's best to make each falling box handle its own movement.

Comment: @MikkoKoivisto With the Op's original approach, you might have 6 variables containing references to destroyed objects too. Fell free to ask the OP about his handling if such scenario, and if it is as you suspect, I'll gladly edit the answer to account for that. But until that is confirmed, I am not going to address something that is not part of the question nor part of the provided code, and simply based on an assumption; if I did that for every answer, I'd go insane. --- However, regarding how the objects should manage themselves\* (\*: on behaviors specific to them), I completely agree! +1

Answer (score 1):

First off all, that's way too many variables. When you find yourself copy and pasting your code you're probably doing something wrong. Just put all those bad boys in some `List<GameObject>` and you can achieve the same result.

What I would recommend is the thing that Mikko Koivisto answered and that is to make another script to handle the actual falling effect of the boxes. But for the sake of keeping it all in one script I handled it differently.

I changed up your code a bit so it's a lot cleaner and more readable. Comments basically tell all the changes.

As for why the old boxes got stuck. You kept overriding your clone variables when you created a new clone. So then in the Update your old clones wouldn't get updated anymore because they're no longer defined in the variable, hence they stopped falling.

> Note: In order for this to work you'll have to add the boxes to your script in the editor, you could also do it in code but it's a lot messier. Just click on the script in the editor, open the boxes list, put size on six and drag them all in there.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Falling : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float fallspeed = 8.0f;
    //removed bool a, b because they never get used anymore

    //"boxes" is public so you can add the boxes in the editor instead of having to do it in your start function
    public List<GameObject> boxes;  //Instead of 6 different variables you could just throw them all in a list
    private List<GameObject> clones; //Same here

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        // makes box_0 fall if a key is pressed
        //Not sure why you were checking if(a) constantly when you set it true 1 line ahead, how could it be false? I took the liberty to remove that
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[0], transform.position, Quaternion.identity)); //No need for different variables, just throw them all in one list
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
             clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[1], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[2], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)))
        {
            clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[3], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
        {
            clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[4], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            clones.Add(Instantiate(boxes[5], transform.position, Quaternion.identity));
        }


        //Instead of checking if any of them exist you can just loop through the list with clones and make them all fall
        foreach (GameObject clone in clones)
        {
            clone.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"for one if I spawn more then one of the same clone they get stuck and I dont think I handled the null gameobject very well at all."

Attach this to every box and remove clone.transform.Translate part from the Falling-script:

```
public class BoxScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fallspeed = 8.0f;
    public bool fall = false;
    void Update () {
        if (fall) {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

...and then when creating new boxes:

```
clone = Instantiate (box_0, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
clone.fall = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a list of box and clones instead so you can factorize your code (I'm not familiar with unity so there might be typos but the general idea would be :

```
        var clones = new List<GameObject>();
        GameObject box = null;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            box = box_0
        }
        // else if ... box = box_1 ...
        // end of your series of else if
        if (box != null)
        {
            clone = Instantiate(box, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            clones.Add(clone);
        }
        box = null;
        //   
        foreach (GameObject clone in clones)
        {
            clone.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * fallspeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World)
        }
```